# Error_Line() is not printing correct line number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I was trying to implement exception handling mechanism in one of my procedure. Its seems like when the sql statement is single line , error_line() in CATCH block return the correct line number but when its a big sql statement, it just does not print the actual line number.

If anyone has come across similar situation, could you please share your thoughts.

Thanks,
Shankar

Comment: You'll need to use `THROW` to raise the unmolested error in T-SQL. Unfortunately, that was introduced in SQL Server 2012 so that's not an option in your case. Maybe it's time to consider upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

The function `ERROR_LINE()` returns the first line number of SQL-statement which throw an exception. To get more information about the error you can use functions `ERROR_MESSAGE()` or `ERROR_NUMBER()` in current `CATCH`-block.